# How to run python code in rapberry pie in background after boot-up and reboot?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, embedded-linux, raspbian

I want to to run my program as soon as raspberry pi boot-up or restart. I've tried `$contab -e` and added program but in log it showed it started but no output nothin. I've to run it manually everyday using `$nohup ./Code &`
even tried adding the run command in `/etc/rc.local` with full path.
How can I run the program then. It's working very well and gives output at normal run.

Comment: Depends on your initialisation system. In general: make it an init service.

Comment: Solved it by making it service.